# Assert a string contains a certain value (and fail the test if it doesn't)

Tags: assert, nightwatch.js

As part of my **nightwatch.js** testing, I have the following code that will list all the values of an element (in this case, a list of UK towns);

```
"Page 2 Location SEO Crawl paths are displayed": function (browser) {
  browser.elements('xpath', '//a[contains(@href,"location")]', function (results) {
    results.value.map(function(element) {
      browser.elementIdAttribute(element.ELEMENT, 'innerText', function(res) {
        var resme = res.value;
          console.log(resme)
      });
    });
  });
},
```

This correctly list all the element values, as such;

[image]

What I'd now like to do is check that **Nottingham** is listed in the result, and **Fail** the test if it's not.

I installed the **assert** npm package to see if that would help, which changed my code to;

```
"Page 2 Location SEO Crawl paths are displayed": function (browser) {
  browser.elements('xpath', '//a[contains(@href,"location")]', function (results) {
    results.value.map(function(element) {
      browser.elementIdAttribute(element.ELEMENT, 'innerText', function(res) {
        var resme = res.value;
        console.log(resme);
          if (resme.includes("Nottingham")) {
            assert.ok(true);
          }
          else {
            assert.ok(false);
        }
      });
    });
  });
},
```

but this didn't work, as I kept getting the following error;

[image]

Is using the **assert** package the best way of testing this, or it there a more straightforward way of asserting that **Nottingham** is included in this list, and the tests **fails** if it's not.

I've tried using `resme.includes("Nottingham")`, but this doesn't fail the test.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the inner-most function (the one that has res as parameter) is called for every item, and resme is the item you are currently iterating, not an array, so the includes function is not working as expected.

I'm not familiar with this library but I guess you have to do something like this:

```
"Page 2 Location SEO Crawl paths are displayed": function (browser) {
  var found = false;
  browser.elements('xpath', '//a[contains(@href,"location")]', function (results) {
    results.value.map(function(element) {
      browser.elementIdAttribute(element.ELEMENT, 'innerText', function(res) {
        var resme = res.value;
        console.log(resme);
        if (resme === "Nottingham") {
          found = true;
          // Maybe return something like null or 0 to stop iterating (would depend on your library).
        }
      });
    });
  });
  assert.ok(found)
},
```

You init a variable "found" with a false value, and when you iterate over every value you set it to true if you find it. Optionally, you should break the iteration at that point. When the whole process is finished, assert that you found the value you wanted.